# How to properly map a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, mapping

I have mapped a servlet like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>FirstServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>s2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>SecondServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>s2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Thing is whenever i write in url

> > case1 :  localhost:2040/SampleError/servlet2/name
> >
> > case2   :  localhost:2040/SampleError/servlet2/name/surname

it goes to same servlet
i know i haven't done url mapping properly please suggest me modification so in case 2 it should show 404 error resources not available

Actually my application name is "SampleError"
This "name" and "surname" in url is dynamic one i mean you can give anything there insead of "name" you can give your name or anything

Comment: I don't see where does the "SampleError" part of your URL come from. Have you tried leaving that out (depending on your servlet container configuration)? Also, does case 1 work?

Comment: your sevlet urls(`/servlet1/*`, `/servlet2/*`) will map to all the url in your application.

Comment: have you exposed `/name/surname` url?

Comment: make sure to include package name: <servlet-class>com.foo.servlet2</servlet-class>

Answer (score 0):

Change your web.xml mapping like this:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>s2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet2/name</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

The pattern `/servlet2/*` means that any URL CONTAINING a `servlet2` string in its **URI** will be mapped to your `SecondServlet`. Thats the reason both `/name` and  `/name/surname` are being handled by your `SecondServlet`

Comment: sorry the name/surname is coming from application i.e i don't know after /servlet/name or /servlet/AnythingElse sorry for your misunderstanding it was my mistake